# Airlock won't stay in carboy

Tags: airlock

This airlock won't stay in my 5-gal glass carboy.

[image]

https://morewinemaking.com/products/universal-stopper-hole.html

I've tried drying out the bung hole and also the bung outer edge, but it still slowly rises and pops out.  This is my masking tape hack to hold it down.  Are there better ones?

What is the proper procedure for installing airlocks?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use this style. I press them all the way down to the lip. Wet or dry they stay put. Take a little work and patience to get out though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is the correct size?

I use the solid type, but what I find is that if I use a #7 bung, it wants to come out so I need to press it down a lot more.   However, if I use a #6.5 (just a bit smaller size), the bung holds well.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a hard look at your airlock. Are you over-filling it? Is it sticking? It sounds like pressure is building up and not bubbling out for some reason.

It could also be time to change out the bung. Poor thing could just be stretched out.